# Can't form a Regexp with a Multiline in Python

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I'm trying to run the following regexp:

```
password_regexp = re.compile(r'''^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+.{6,}$''')
```

It works as intended. For the sake of readability, I decided to space it out since it is a multiline:

```
password_regexp = re.compile(r'''(
    ^(?=.*[a-z])
    (?=.*[A-Z])
    (?=.*\d)
    .+.{6,}$
    )''')
```

When I run the following code (which worked with the one-line version):

```
why = password_regexp.search(password)
why.group()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Why? The one-line version worked, why would placing it on multiple lines with ''' ruin it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `re.VERBOSE` flag and remove the extra parenthesis.

```
password_regexp = re.compile(r'''
    ^(?=.*[a-z])
    (?=.*[A-Z])
    (?=.*\d)
    .+.{6,}$
''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Literally was just about to delete, thanks for the help!